# CSS for Show full width card below each small card for each row

Tags: html, css, css-position, cardview

I have scenario, where I have design of 3 column/row cards of multiple row. When user click on any card then a full width card will show just below that row with more details. As per my CSS, full width card is showing just below the row. But I have issue that.

When I click on first small card then full width data show just below that row, but Other cards in that row shifted below that row.  The below image will describe more clearly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra row of row-length cards below each normal row. Inside those extra rows, you could include 3 row-length cards with the extra details, all of which are not normally displayed. Then, when each card is clicked, the corresponding row-length card of that card could be displayed.

This is just one example of how to solve this. I hope this helps.